# How Do I Escape From TimeStamp, even though I write my own currentTimeMillis method?

Tags: grails, timestamp

I have a inetgration test case like this :

```
void testSomething() {
       def cardTable = new CardStorage();
        cardTable.cardSecurityCode = "something"
        def date = new Date() 
        System.metaClass.static.currentTimeMillis = { 
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,11);
            cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE,0);
            cal.set(Calendar.SECOND,0);
            cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND,0);
            return date.getTime()
        } 
        assert cardTable.save(flush:true) //this works.
}
```

The line : `cardTable.save(flush:true)`  is working. It asserts `true`. But the problem is that the `dateCreated` field is still the same as (`new Date()`). I wonder,how this can happen. Because I have coded the `currentTimeMillis` method as per my req. But still grails doesn't pick it up. But I'm sure that my new `currentTimeMillis` is working (because making error in it, results in a compilation error).

Where I'm missing? How can I disable the timeStamp feature for testing alone?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java code in core library in `new Date()` does not and will never pick up your changes in Groovy metaclass code.

I can recommend using [joda-time](http://grails.org/plugin/joda-time) (make `dateCreated` a `DateTime`) and [setting current time by its means](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/userguide.html#Change_the_Current_Time).

Even better way is not to tie your code to the current time, but to pass the time into your class from outside.

Comment: Passing the time to class from outside? How can I do that?

Comment: Like `new CardStorage(builtOn: new Date())`, where I suppose `builtOn` to be some business logic field. Another point is that in your sample you're actually testing Grails, which you normally need not do at all. We need to test the code WE wrote ;)

Answer (score 0):

Dont use 'dateCreated', grails will automatically fill it in for you.